# .htaccess rewrite rule dont work when there is query string in url

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, server

I am having trouble configuring rewrite rules.I need that mysite.com/blog/start redirects to anothersite.com/start , the redirect is working fine, the problem is that this dont work if there is some query string in the origin url:

1. mysite.com/blog/start -> to anothersite.com/start ( works fine)
2. mysite.com/blog/start/ -> to anothersite.com/start ( works fine)
3. mysite.com/blog/start/?param=123 -> to anothersite.com/start ( dont work)

This is the rewrite section in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #redirects
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^start$ http://anothersite.com/start [L]
    RewriteRule ^blog/start$ http://anothersite.com/start [L,QSA]
    ...
    ...

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` instead `QSA` flag

```
RewriteRule ^blog/start$ http://anothersite.com/start%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```